# Multivariable double integrals using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I have to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{\sqrt{3x}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}dydx$$

I drew the domain of integration, and I found that :
$$ 0 \leq r \leq 2 $$

$$0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/3$$

Assuming what I found is correct, I how can I rewrite the integral?

I know $ dydx $ becomes $rdrd\theta$, and $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $r$.

Do I convert $x$ to $rcos\theta$ ? This will yield me the answer of $2\sqrt{3}$ after integration, but I cant find any online calculator to verify this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The smallest value of $\theta$ in your region is indeed $\pi/3$, but $\theta$ takes values in the range $[\pi/3,\pi/2]$ (draw a picture to convince yourself). You also have to be careful because the domain is not a sector of a circle, so the limits of integration in polar coordinates are not constant. For values of $\theta$ close to $\pi/3$ you intersect your region twice.. I do not think polar coordinates are a good choice here.

Comment: Exercise specifies to solve this with polar coordinates unfortunately..

I see my mistake regarding $\theta$, thank you . How would you advise me to progress from here with polar coordinates?

Comment: Is it possible that your lower limit in $y$ is actually $\sqrt{3}x$ instead of $\sqrt{3x}$? If that is the case, the region is indeed a sector and all you need is constant limits $[0,2]$ for $r$ and $[\pi/3,\pi/2]$ for $\theta$.

Comment: @GReyes youre amazing! I really didnt notice due to how small it was written.. that makes is so much more simple. Thank you very much! Please comment so I can accept your answer :)

Comment: My pleasure.  I just realized it could not be that hard...